# Python comparing unrelated types succeeds even with no operator defined

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a trivial class that has no members, but I can apparently still use relational comparison operators:

```
>>> class A(object): pass
... 
>>> 1 < A()
True
>>> A() < 1
False
```

Furthermore, *any* int or double compares less than `A()`. Strings compare greater than `A()`:

```
>>> 'hi' < A()
False
```

`A()` inconsistently compares against itself:

```
>>> A() < A()
True
>>> A() < A()
False
```

But never to `B`:

```
>>> class B: pass
... 
>>> A() < B()
False
>>> A() < B()
False
>>> A() < B()
False
```

How is this not an error? What sorcery is this?!

Comment: This has been asked a lots of times: [**CPython implementation detail**: Objects of different types except numbers are ordered by their type names; objects of the same types that don’t support proper comparison are ordered by their address.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons)

Comment: There is no sourcery. There is only the decision in Python (rescinded for Python 3) to make everything orderable.

Comment: And without explicit ordering instances of the same class are ordered by their memory id. `A()` is consistently ordered, but you need to avoid letting Python re-use the memory location..

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Pick a duplicate and close?

Comment: For your `A() < A()` comparison, the order is determined by their `id()` address. This means they can end up anywhere on the heap and it is easily possible for the second object to get a lower memory address than the first. Or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

It's Python sorcery!

Python has stock comparison methods which it will add to your class unless you override them.

I would imagine that you're getting the result of whether the object's handle is less than the other, so you won't necessarily get a meaningful result (or the result you expected), which is why we overload these comparison operators to give more meaningful results.

Hope this helps!